# All possible possible directed graphs in V={1,2,3}

Tags: graph

I got this exercise :

> Give an example of three different directed graphs on V = {1, 2, 3}
> where the edges (1, 2) and (1, 3) exist. Write both the adjacency-list and adjacency-
> matrix representation for each.

I find only this two:

> G = {(1,2), (1,3)}
>
> G = {(1,2), (1,3), (2,3)}

What I miss? Something like that is valid: G = {(1,2), (1,3), (3,2)} ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a directed graph, which means all links are one-way. If you want to be able to go from 1 to 2 *and* from 2 to 1, you need two links, (1,2) and (2,1) - that's part of the definition of a *directed* graph.

With that, enumerate all possible links for a graph of 3 vertexes:

- (1,2)
- (2,1)
- (1,3)
  ...

Once you enumerate all possible links in such a graph, you can pick and choose unique sets of those links to make into multiple graphs, subject to the constraints given to you by the exercise.

For instance, here are a couple graphs:

- {(1,2)}
- {(2,1)}
- {(1,3)}
- {(3,1)}
- {(3,2), (2,1), (1,3)}

...

You already have two out of three requested answers and you need a third graph to complete the exercise. You need to give answers that include two provided links. Why not give as an answer a graph that has *every* link in it? A graph of every link must contain the two requested links, right?